# Class variables set in onActivityResult are reset when method returns

Tags: android

I have an activity which lets the user select a phone number. Naturally, I'd like my class to remember the id of the contact selected, so I save this in a class field.  However when the method onActivityResult returns, my class variable is reset.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, People.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT); 

    ...

    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, intent);       
        switch(reqCode){
            case(PICK_CONTACT):
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    Uri contactData = intent.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if(c.moveToFirst()){
                        contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People.NAME));
                        contactId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(People._ID));

        break;
```

When I set a breakpoint within this method, the values for contactName and contactId are as I expect, however once the method returns, the values somehow get reset to their defaults.  Clearly I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or forgetting.

Thanks!

Iva

Comment: Wondering if you're running in development mode and perhaps Rails is reloading your class definition each time?

Comment: I'm running into the same thing. I know it's been 8 years but any idea what was going wrong?

Comment: FYI, found out what was going on. Essentially, the Activity was being suspended to make room for the Intent and it has to re-create your Activity after returning from the Intent, thus resetting your instance variables. You get around this by either restarting the device or handling it with `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`. Read more here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359130/why-oncreate-method-called-after-startactivityforresult?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 3):

### It's Possible that your `Activity` is being Suspended and Re-created.

Essentially, if the Intent you're launching with `startActivityForResult` is resource-intensive enough, the OS might have to suspend your Activity to free up resources.

So it saves what it can and then returning from the Intent to call `onActivityResult`, it has to re-create your Activity. Any instance variables will be reset in this case.

You get around this by either restarting the device or handling it with `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

Read more here:
[Why oncreate method called after startActivityForResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359130/why-oncreate-method-called-after-startactivityforresult?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need help with this. onActivityResult is called before onResume when your activity is restarting. Make sure you are not resetting the variable values in onResume.

> You will receive this call immediately before onResume() when your activity is re-starting.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 0):

May be your configuration is changing when you open new Activity. Try to put `configChanges` on your activity in AndroidManifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```