# Why oncreate method called after startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, image-gallery

In my application i want to select image from `Gallery` and set the image in `ListView`. In my ListView`I have 16 rows. So when ever item click in`ListView`open the gallery and set the image to`ListView`. But my problem is some times after`startActivityForResult()`,`oncreate()` method called. This is the onclick code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_PICTURE);
```

And this is the onactivityresult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("result", "result");
    displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    Ew = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    Eh = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

    switch (requestcode) {
    case SELECT_PICTURE:
        if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {

            lelListLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            relImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            ExifInterface exif = null;
            // Bitmap bmRotated = null;

            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImagePath);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                    ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
            Log.e("Orientation==>", "" + orientation);

            try {

                bmRotated = null;
                bmGallayImage = null;
                trimCache();
                bmGallayImage = convertBitmap(selectedImagePath);
                bmRotated = InventorySubmitImagesActivity.rotateBitmap(
                        bmGallayImage, orientation);

                // if(bmRotated.getWidth()>bmRotated.getHeight()){
                if (bmRotated.getWidth() > 1024) {
                    float x = 0;
                    x = 1024 / (float) bmRotated.getWidth();
                    // Log.e("x====","value "+x);

                    bmRotated = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmRotated, 1024,
                            (int) (bmRotated.getHeight() * x), true);
                }
                /*
                 * }else{ if(bmRotated.getHeight() > 1024){ float x=0;
                 * x=1024/(float)bmRotated.getHeight();
                 * Log.e("x====","value "+x);
                 * 
                 * bmRotated = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmRotated,
                 * (int)(bmRotated.getWidth()*x), 1024, true); } }
                 */


                Eh = Eh - ll_buttonlayout.getHeight();


                float iw = bmRotated.getWidth();
                float ih = bmRotated.getHeight();



                float diff = Ew / iw;

                float layoutwidth = Ew;
                float layoutheight = diff * ih;

                if (layoutheight > Eh) {

                    diff = Eh / ih;
                    layoutwidth = Ew * diff;
                    layoutheight = Eh;
                }

                bmGallayImage = bmRotated;
                if (bmRotated != null) {

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            (int) layoutwidth, (int) layoutheight);
                    relImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


                    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bmRotated);
                    old_width = bmRotated.getWidth();
                    old_height = bmRotated.getHeight();

                    relImage.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

                }
                left = (int) layoutwidth / 2 - 34;
                top = (int) layoutheight / 2 - 8;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // drag_check=true;
            relImage.removeAllViews();

            imgMarker = new ImageView(this);
            final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            relImage.addView(imgMarker, layoutParams);
            imgMarker.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
            bmdragImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.image_marker);
            imgMarker.setImageBitmap(bmdragImage);

            matrix = new Matrix();
            savedMatrix = new Matrix();
            oldDist = 0f;
            start = new PointF();
            mid = new PointF();

            matrix.postTranslate(left, top);
            imgMarker.setImageMatrix(matrix);

            imgMarker.setOnTouchListener(RefurbishmentImageActivity.this);
            imgMarker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // end..
            // }

        }
        break;
```

}
}

In this `ListView` after selecting 6 or 7 images oncreate method called, before the `onactivityresult()`. But after `oncreate()` method again startactivity result called. Please guide me what is the problem. Thanks InAdvance to all..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> before the onactivityresult(). But after oncreate() method again startactivity result called

when Activity is sent to background (when other activity becomes on top of it, or when it is sent by the home button to background)  its instance is kept alive as long as the system is not under memory pressure.  when the system doesn't have enough memory to do whatever it's currently doing in foreground, it usually will re-claim memory by stopping and releasing from memory background activities.

in that case - the system provide you with the [`Activity.onSaveInstanceState`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) callback which will be invoked from the activity that's going to be killed to provide you a chance to save any state needed to be saved before it's being killed.

when your activity will return to foreground - it will be re-created (that's why [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) called again),  with savedInstanceState parameter that will not be null.

the savedInstanceState will hold bundle with all the extras you provided in the onSavedInstanceState() callback.

this is very important to understand.

for better understanding, I advise you to read seriously - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Comment: I'm an experienced developer and yet I never though about this issue with startActivityForResult. But when I had the issue it was so obvious.

Comment: Holy schnikeys! Didn't even know this existed and I've been doing Android dev for about 6 years. I only got burnt by this because the tablet being tested hadn't been restarted for quite some time. I was trying to capture a photo using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` which was killing the Activity and causing all my instance variables to clear. The trickiest part was that it wasn't doing that when capturing a video using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` or when importing from the Gallery. Just taking a photo - maybe because the stock photo app has more controls and requires more memory. Restarted and it's fine!

Answer (score 1):

May be dialog with selection chooser is too huge for the system and it reduces memory by caching your application. Check is method [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) called before `onCreate`. If yes, then you can save needed data in bundle and load it in `onCreate` method

Comment: is this memory issue or any other problem?

Comment: this is can be caused by image chooser - you launch it 6-7 times, he allocates a lot of memory and then system need to call memory cleaner tool

Comment: the best way to fix this is to implement saveInstanceState mechanism, because you cannot touch chooser - user may use another bad one