# Not able to update views at onActivityResult in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onactivityresult

I have a fragment where I am getting image data from my custom gallery at `onActivityResult` then I need to update my `TextView` and `ImageView` when on `onActivityResult` called. I tried several ways from StackOverflow and GitHub but none is working for me. I checked in the log that I am getting image successfully with a path like this `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190430_221429.jpg` i also check whether its valid path or not.

**Upload Image Fragment**

```
public class UploadImage_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public static final String TAG="###Upload Image###";
    TextView uploadText;
    ImageView uploadImage;
    Button uploadButton;
    App_Functions functions;
    String cmpImage,Base64Image;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_profile_cover_registration,container,false);

        uploadText = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewImageUpload);
        uploadImage = v.findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
        uploadButton = v.findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);

        uploadButton.setEnabled(false);

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.cam_icon).into(uploadImage);

        uploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int clickID=view.getId();
        switch (clickID){
            case R.id.uploadImage:
                Media_Gallery gallery = new Media_Gallery();
                gallery.setTargetFragment(this,101);
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTrasaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTrasaction.addToBackStack("Chat");
                fragmentTrasaction.replace(R.id.FragmentLoginRegistration,gallery,"Chat");
                fragmentTrasaction.commit();

                break;
            case R.id.uploadButton:
                if (uploadButton.isEnabled()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Button Is Enable Upload Image Here");
                    uploadButton.setEnabled(false);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Select Image To Upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        functions=new App_Functions(getActivity());
        if (requestCode==301 && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            cmpImage = functions.compressImage(uri,true);
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(cmpImage).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(uploadImage);
            uploadButton.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d(TAG,"Image "+uri+" Compress Image "+cmpImage);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cmpImage);
            Base64Image=functions.Convert_To_Base64(bitmap);

        }else if (requestCode == 101 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> imagePath = data.getStringArrayListExtra("Profile");
            if (imagePath!=null){
                String image = imagePath.get(0);
                Log.d(TAG,"Image Path "+image);

                uploadText.setText("Hey I am New Test"); // Not working

                uploadImage.setImageDrawable(null);
                uploadImage.invalidate();

                File file = new File(image);
                Uri newPath = Uri.fromFile(file);

                Log.d(TAG,"Check File "+file);
                Log.d(TAG,"Check Uri  "+newPath);
                Log.d(TAG,"Check ImageView  "+uploadImage);

                Glide.with(getActivity()).load(image).into(uploadImage); // Not working
            }
        }
    }




    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uploadImage.setImageDrawable(null);
        uploadImage.invalidate();
    }
}
```

I tried several things like invalidate, Setting image view.setBitmapImage(null) but none work for me also I tried to update textview also but it also not working for me. Please help

Comment: Did you mean to put uploadImage.setDrawable(null) in onResume? From memory onActivityResult runs onResume after, so your onResume code clears the image you put in the imageview just after you assign it. (If I'm remembering right.)

Comment: @Matt yes that was my last try. earlier it was just above when i update imageview `onActivityResult`

Comment: did you try to change any other view in your onactivityresult?

Comment: Yes i tried to change my textview also but not updating on UI

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere that you are calling startActivityForResult.  Are you sure that your onActivityResult is even getting called?

Comment: @MichaelDougan as i am using custom gallery. i am using gettargerfragment.onactiivityresult which called back fragment onactivityresult

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not update the view directly from `onActivityResult` method as it can be called just before your activity is about to be destroyed and recreated.

[Tal Kanel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26360028/1129332) provides a good explanation about it:

Comment: Thanks i think your answer would help me. can you explain bit more as per my question. As you can check my code i am checking whether my `ImageView` is null or not , and getting its reference

Comment: @Ritu during the `onActivityResult` you should only save your state and make the actual update to your views `onStart`(preferably) or `onResum`

Comment: Thanks alot but can you please tell me onActivityResult also calls on UI thread and why my views updates at onResume

Comment: @Ritu Yes, onActivityResult is called on the UI thread, not sure about your other question.